# AD FS Login Authentication By Bypassing Default Login Page

Tags: ios, swift, single-sign-on, adfs, adfs3.0

I am trying to create a scenario in my ios native app in which I want to do the login via AD FS by bypassing its default login page and provide login credentials like a rest api call, something like following:

https://adfs.theapp.com/authorize?username=user&pass=123&client_id=something&redirect_uri=something

If bypassing like above is not possible then is there any way we can bypass the login page and do the authentication purely through passing variables to authorize? If so please let me know how to do that?

Basically what I am trying to do is, Once the user has logged in the first time in my app via AD FS, so everytime he comes back to use the app he is not asked to login again just like how its done in facebook app. You just login once. So basically I just want to do something like that, let me know if its possible and if it is please suggest me something I can work with?

Comment: Are they logging in, just to use your app or so that they can access some other resource?  For the latter you would normally save the token that is returned from the authentication process and just use that, refreshing it as required, until the refresh fails. At that point you get the user to authenticate again. The point of SAML authentication flows like ADFS is that the relying party doesn't get to see the user's password.

Comment: You would typically use something like Microsoft's ADALios framework to manage this for you. ADALios supports brokered authentication using the MS Authenticator app, if it installed.  This gives a nice SSO experience if/when an organisation adopts Azure AD and supports conditional access rules for mfa etc